# Importing matplotlib is stopping python script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed *matplotlib* for *python 34* which I am using.

I have also installed the other modules that it requires such as six and numpy using *pip*.

I tried to write a *basic python script* to create a simple graph but whenever I ran it, nothing happened.

I eventually figured out that anything that I did after the line
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` or just `import matplotlib` was not run.
Why would importing *matplotlib* cause my python script to stop?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10])
plt.show()
print('test')
```

When I run the above code nothing happens. I moved the print('test') line around and 'test' will only appear if that line is run before the line where matplotlib is imported. I have imported matplotlib in IDLE and it worked fine but it doesn't work in any scripts.

Comment: Please, include your code that replicates the problem.

Comment: Do you mean python 3.4?